# Changing background color to transparent in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, sld

How to set the background color to transparent. I want use style which describe in *.sld file for all my photo with tif format. How to do that?

[image]

Comment: rather than posting new questions please say why this answer doesn't work for you. You need to edit this question with the SLD you are using

Answer (score 6):

Here an example to create one transparent classe. You will use `opacity="0.0"` parameter:

```
<sld:ColorMap>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#000000" opacity="0.0" quantity="-999"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#111111" opacity="1.0"quantity="1.0"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#AAAAAA" opacity="1.0"quantity="100.0"/>
</sld:ColorMap>
```